# Infinite menu animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, menu

I'm coding an infinite vertical menu but I'm having trouble with the animation. I can't manage to make (**without Jquery please**) the scroll smoother.

I want to animate the addition and deletion of the 'noheight' class.  The aim is that the appearance and disappearance of 'li' should not be abrupt, but should have a translational effect. I'd like to add a duration to the addition/deletion of the class but I don't know how to do it in classic js.
I tried to animate the noheight class with queries on the css side but it doesn't work. I would have to animate the addition of the class on the JS side?

A repeat of my code when clicking on another item in the list (On the functional level, it works perfectly, but on the animation level, it's very austere) :

```
function menuClick(elementClicked) {
let indexActive = searchActiveElement();

let gap = getIndex(elementClicked) < indexActive ? indexActive - getIndex(elementClicked) : getIndex(elementClicked) - indexActive;

for(let i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
    indexActive = searchActiveElement();
    if(getIndex(elementClicked) !== indexActive) {
        ul.children[indexActive].classList.remove('active');
        if(getIndex(elementClicked) < indexActive) {
            // If the user clicks above the active element (the menu will go down)
            ul.children[indexActive].previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
            ul.lastElementChild.remove();
            ul.lastElementChild.classList.add('noHeight');
            ul.firstElementChild.classList.remove('noHeight');

            let newElement = document.createElement('li');
            newElement.classList.add('noHeight');
            newElement.innerHTML =  ul.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
            ul.firstElementChild.before(newElement);

            ul.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function() {
                menuClick(this);
            });
        }
```

The menu can be tested here : http://jsfiddle.net/3u8c2xb5/

Thanks in advance for your answers :D

Comment: What property are you trying to animate? What is the desired animation effect?

Comment: I apologise for this lack of detail. I want to animate the addition and deletion of the 'noheight' class.  The aim is that the appearance and disappearance of 'li' should not be abrupt, but should have a translational effect. I'd like to add a duration to the addition/deletion of the class but I don't know how to do it in js.